# How to replace only 4 bits of 1 byte?

Tags: java, kotlin, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I know I can store and retrieve 2 numbers of 4 bits inside 1 Byte like this :

```
// Store both numbers in one byte
byte firstNumber = 10;
byte secondNumber = 15;
byte bothNumbers = (byte) ((firstNumber << 4) | secondNumber);

// Retreive the original numbers
firstNumber = (byte) ((bothNumbers >> 4) & (byte) 0x0F);
secondNumber = (byte) (bothNumbers & 0x0F);
```

But how can I overwrite one of the two numbers (let's say the first one (10)) without touching the last 4 bits (15)?

```
// Store both numbers in one byte
byte firstNumber = 10;
byte secondNumber = 15;
byte bothNumbers = (byte) ((firstNumber << 4) | secondNumber);

// Replacing one of the 2 numbers without touching the other
firstNumber = 13;
bothNumbers = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, you could create a value class to make it convenient to work with. It only compiles to a Byte, but you can conveniently treat it like a class instance/ boxable primitive.

```kotlin
@JvmInline
value class FourBitPair(val bothNumbers: Byte) {
    constructor(firstNumber: Byte, secondNumber: Byte):
            this((firstNumber.toInt() shl 4 or secondNumber.toInt()).toByte())

    val firstNumber: Byte get() = ((bothNumbers.toInt() shr 4) and 0xF).toByte()
    val secondNumber: Byte get() = (bothNumbers.toInt() and 0xF).toByte()

    operator fun component1() = firstNumber
    operator fun component2() = secondNumber

    fun withFirstNumber(newFirstNumber: Byte) = FourBitPair(newFirstNumber, secondNumber)
    fun withSecondNumber(newSecondNumber: Byte) = FourBitPair(firstNumber, newSecondNumber)

    override fun toString(): String = "[$firstNumber, $secondNumber]"
}
```

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val x: Byte = 3
    val y: Byte = 15
    var pair = FourBitPair(x, y)
    println(pair)
    pair = pair.withFirstNumber(13)
    println(pair)
    pair = pair.withSecondNumber(4)
    println(pair)
    val (first, second) = pair
    println(second)
    println(pair.bothNumbers)
}
```

Prints:

```
[3, 15]
[13, 15]
[13, 4]
4
-44
```

Comment: Wow, very nice class. Very useful. It helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You would use something like this:

```
bothNumbers = (byte) ((bothNumbers & 0xf) | (firstNumber << 4))
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of how this works (using AND to mask the number being replaced out of the combined byte, and then using OR to add that in)?

Comment: @gidds All the ingredients are already in the question. My answer just inlines the secondNumber = (byte) (bothNumbers & 0x0F); part.